# Calculation of the g-force acting on people in a fake fun ride

Tags: forces, centrifugal-force

I saw this video: https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=622261007879030&set=vb.100002854081079&type=2&theater

If you go to minute 1 and 2 seconds you see a fun ride in action. Obviously this is fake, but I'm asking myself how much force will act on those people? Intuitively it seems to me, that this will be more than 5 or 6 g and thus people will become unconscious. It does not need to be an exact value, but an approxmation will do, e.g. more than 6G or less?

So is it possible to calculate (approximatively of course) the force acting on those people in the ride by making some simplifying assumptions? The complexitiy of the movement exceeds my physics skills, but it somehow must be possible by e.g. estimating the angular speed based on the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 1:02 in that video, you see the "people" at the end of the swing do something like a half revolution with a radius of 15 meter in 0.3 seconds (rough estimate of dimensions and time - feel free to come up with your own estimates by counting frames etc - then substitute those numbers in the equations below).

The centrifugal acceleration is given by

$$a = \omega^2\ r$$

Half a rotation in 0.3 seconds means $\omega = \frac{\pi}{0.3} \approx 10$, and so acceleration is

$$a = 1500 m/s^2$$

This is about 150 g, which is clearly not physiologically possible.

Not sure how some of these movie clips were generated, but that's not a real ride shown at real speed...